# composer require: prevent "Updating dependencies (including require-dev)"

Tags: performance, composer-php

Am I able to speed up `composer require <package>` by somehow disabling the `Updating dependencies` step? I'm just interested in installing one simple package and not reading all other packages. Making it verbose shows the many, many reads it will do.

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2017-2.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2017-1.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2016-4.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2016-3.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2016-2.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2016-1.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2015-4.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2015-3.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2015-2.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2015-1.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2014-4.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2014-3.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2014-2.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2014-1.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2013-4.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2013-3.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2013-2.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2013-1.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2012-4.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2012-3.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2012-2.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2012-1.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2011-4.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2011-3.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/drupal-provider-2011-2.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2016.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2016-07.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2016-10.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2017-01.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2017-04.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-archived.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-latest.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-drupal-composer$drupal-scaffold.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-cweagans$composer-patches.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-composer$installers.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-zendframework$zend-stdlib.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-zendframework$zend-escaper.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-zendframework$zend-feed.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-zendframework$zend-hydrator.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-psr$http-message.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-zendframework$zend-diactoros.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-twig$twig.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$polyfill-mbstring.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$translation.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$validator.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-ircmaxell$password-compat.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$polyfill-php55.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$serializer.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$routing.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$polyfill-php54.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$http-foundation.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$psr-http-message-bridge.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$polyfill-iconv.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-psr$log.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$debug.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$event-dispatcher.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$http-kernel.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$polyfill-apcu.json from cache
Reading /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$class-loader.json from cache
... Goes on...
```

Comment: have you tried `composer require <package> --no-update`? see https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require

Comment: That seems to do the trick! Thanks! We periodically update all packages by hand, so, I do not necessarily need to update all dependencies when requiring a new one. Does it have any other side effects I need to know about? You might want to convert this to an answer btw.

Comment: Hm... I've just tried this again, but it seems that the package does not get installed with `--no-update`? It does update the `composer.json`.

Comment: In this case are you sure the package would be installable without changing any other packages? i would guess that the minimum dependencies of your newly required package conflict with some of the other packages you have installed

Comment: I'm not sure... But, isn't there a way to just make sure only the dependencies get checked? Since without `--no-update` it seems to check every single package in the project (see code in original question).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that

```
composer require <package> --no-update
```

only updates composer.json with definitions for your new package. To actually install the package, you afterwards need to run:

```
composer update --no-dev <package>
```

This will install the package without installing development packages.